# How to escape a path in PHP

Tags: php

Basically I want to put C:\cameraTest\something\ into a single quoted string, but I'm not entirely sure how to properly escape the final backslash as it ends up escaping the single quote if I do so. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Escaping a backslash is \\

Comment: You can find this information in the PHP manual under "strings". Additionally, you can use forward slashes (which work and do not need to be escaped) as in your question instead of backslashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That string doesn't have any backslash characters. It has only forward slashes, which are not escape characters and don't require special treatment in strings.

If it did have backslash characters, they would be escaped with another backslash.

```
'foo\\' # foo\
```

Comment: Whoops my bad, I'll edit the entry to use the correct slashes

Answer (score 1):

Use double backslashes. The first one will escape the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider using forwardslashes instead of backslashes. If I'm not mistaken, Windows can work with both most as directory separator characters while other operating systems work with forwardslashes.

If you are trying to put the directory in a string to use it later, that might be helpful.